# Oracle 10g: aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Got the following tables:

**Table T**

```
DATE_A    | DATE_B    | ERRCODE 
----------+-----------+--------
01/MAY/13 | 01/JUN/15 | X
01/DEC/17 | 01/FEB/18 | Y
```

**Table U**

```
ERRCODE | ERRDESC
--------+-------------------------------------------
X       | Conflicting from : {1} and to Period : {2}
Y       | Periods : {1} and {2} overlap
```

The following code:

```
select period, wm_concat(errcode) as issues
from ((select DATE_A as period, errcode from T where DATE_A is not null) union all
      (select DATE_B, errcode from T where DATE_B is not null)
     ) di
group by period
order by period;
```

will transform the `Table T` as follow:

```
PERIOD    | ISSUES
----------+--------
01/MAY/13 | X
01/JUN/15 | X
01/DEC/17 | Y
01/FEB/18 | Y
```

I would like to transform the code above so that:

- it replace the ERRCODE from  the table `T` with the corresponding `ERRDESC` from table `U`
- replace `{1}` and `{2}` in ERRDESC with respectively `DATE_A` and `DATE_B`
- Insert the result in `Table V`

So I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO v (
    period,
    issues
)
    SELECT
        period,
        wm_concat(issue) AS issues
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                t.date_a AS period,
                replace( (
                    SELECT
                        u.errdesc AS issue
                    FROM
                        u
                    WHERE
                        t.errcode = u.errcode
                ),'{1}', t.date_a) AS issue
            FROM
                t
            WHERE
                t.date_a IS NOT NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                t.date_b,
                replace( (
                    SELECT
                        u.errdesc AS issue
                    FROM
                        u
                    WHERE
                        t.errcode = u.errcode
                ),'{2}', t.date_b)
            FROM
                t
            WHERE
                t.date_b IS NOT NULL
        ) di
    GROUP BY
        period;
```

But I'm getting this (`Table V`):

```
PERIOD    | ISSUES
----------+--------
01/MAY/13 | Conflicting from : 01/MAY/13 and to Period : {2}
01/JUN/15 | Conflicting from : {1} and to Period : 01/JUN/15
01/DEC/17 | Periods : 01/DEC/17 and {2} overlap
01/FEB/18 | Periods : {1} and 01/FEB/18 overlap
```

Instead of the result I'm looking for (`Table V`):

```
PERIOD    | ISSUES
----------+--------
01/MAY/13 | Conflicting from : 01/MAY/13 and to Period : 01/JUN/15
01/JUN/15 | Conflicting from : 01/MAY/13 and to Period : 01/JUN/15
01/DEC/17 | Periods : 01/DEC/17 and 01/FEB/18 overlap
01/FEB/18 | Periods : 01/DEC/17 and 01/FEB/18 overlap
```

The reason being that the select before the union all don't know about `date_b` and the select after don't know about `date_a`.

**Question**

How should modify the latest code to get the expected result ?

**Note**

```
CREATE TABLE T
   (     
    "DATE_A" DATE, 
    "DATE_B" DATE, 
    "ERRCODE" VARCHAR2(2)
   )  ;

Insert into T (DATE_A,DATE_B,ERRCODE) values (to_date('01/MAY/13','DD/MON/RR'),to_date('01/JUN/15','DD/MON/RR'),'X');
Insert into T (DATE_A,DATE_B,ERRCODE) values (to_date('01/DEC/17','DD/MON/RR'),to_date('01/FEB/18','DD/MON/RR'),'Y');

CREATE TABLE U
   (     
    "ERRCODE"  VARCHAR2(2), 
    "ERRDESC"  VARCHAR2(100)
   )  ;

Insert into U (ERRCODE, ERRDESC) values ('X','Conflicting from : {1} and to Period : {2}');
Insert into U (ERRCODE, ERRDESC) values ('Y','Periods : {1} and {2} overlap');

CREATE TABLE V
   (     
    "PERIOD"  DATE, 
    "ISSUES"  VARCHAR2(100)
   )  ;

commit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd do it is to first join the two tables and populate the values in the error description column, then split that into two rows, like so:

```
INSERT INTO v (period, issues)
WITH t AS (SELECT to_date('01/05/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_a, to_date('01/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_b, 'X' errcode FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT to_date('01/12/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_a, to_date('01/02/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_b, 'Y' errcode FROM dual),
     u AS (SELECT 'X' errcode, 'Conflicting from : {1} and to Period : {2}' errdesc FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Y' errcode, 'Periods : {1} and {2} overlap' errdesc FROM dual),
 dummy AS (SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2),
   res AS (SELECT t.date_a,
                  t.date_b,
                  REPLACE(REPLACE(u.errdesc, '{1}', to_char(t.date_a, 'dd/MON/yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')), '{2}', to_char(t.date_b, 'dd/MON/yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')) errdesc
           FROM   t
                  INNER JOIN u ON t.errcode = u.errcode)
SELECT CASE WHEN d.rn = 1 THEN res.date_a
            WHEN d.rn = 2 THEN res.date_b
       END period,
       errdesc
FROM   res
       CROSS JOIN dummy d
ORDER BY res.date_a, d.rn;

PERIOD      ERRDESC
----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/05/2013  Conflicting from : 01/MAY/2013 and to Period : 01/JUN/2015
01/06/2015  Conflicting from : 01/MAY/2013 and to Period : 01/JUN/2015
01/12/2017  Periods : 01/DEC/2017 and 01/FEB/2018 overlap
01/02/2018  Periods : 01/DEC/2017 and 01/FEB/2018 overlap
```

This is a kind of unpivot; if you were in 11g or above, you'd be able to take advantage of the `UNPIVOT` command to split the rows out into two. It works by creating a dummy subquery that contains the required amount of rows you want to output for each of your input rows - in your case, that's 2.

Then we can cross join that to the main result set, meaning that the rows are duplicated. Then it's just a matter of working out which columns to show on each row, and voila!

Just a couple of notes about the dates:

- Please always explicitly convert your dates to strings, rather than relying on the nls_date_format setting; what you might have in your session might be completely different to someone else's.
- Years have four digits. Please don't use 2 digits and force Oracle to guess, especially when you know the information up front! There may come a time when you get an unexpected result from using the 'RR' format mask.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Much appreciated!

Comment: Obviously for your case, you wouldn't need the t and u subqueries; those are just there in my query to mimic your t and u tables with data in.

Comment: Im wondering why I'm getting duplicate removing t, u (12 rows instead of 4 expect). But getting 4 indeed keeping t,u. Still, if I can fix that, I think your solution is more professionnal and will adopt it then.

Comment: Seems like the data in your t and u tables doesn't match the data in my t and u subqueries, if you're getting different results by removing the t and u subqueries. I also assumed that u.errcode was a primary key.

Comment: please edit your question to include the exact data that's in your t and u tables. My query shouldn't work any differently if you don't include the t and u subqueries **as long as** the data in your actual t and u tables matches that in the t and u subqueries. I can only conclude that the tables must hold different data.

Comment: Sorry, you are right ! My U table got duplicate. Apologize. Thanks. Marked correct and up voted !

Comment: That's why I mentioned that I assumed u.errcode was the primary key. I would say that having more than one row for an error code in a lookup table to find the corresponding error description is not good database design - typically, you'd only have a single row in the lookup table per error code, meaning only a single error description could be returned. That saves having to work out which row to select whenever you query the table (i.e. no distincts necessary, also what if there were two rows for one error code, but with different error descriptions?).

Comment: Definitely. There should have been a PK, missed it, really. Thanks pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Got it work with the simple solution (below):

```
INSERT INTO v (
    period,
    issues
)
    SELECT
        period,
        wm_concat(issue) AS issues
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                date_a AS period,
                replace(replace( (
                    SELECT 
                        u.errdesc AS issue
                    FROM
                        u
                    WHERE
                        t.errcode = u.errcode
                ),'{1}',t.date_a),'{2}',t.date_b) AS issue
            FROM
                t
            WHERE
                date_a IS NOT NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                date_b,
                replace(replace( (
                    SELECT 
                        u.errdesc AS issue
                    FROM
                        u
                    WHERE
                        t.errcode = u.errcode
                ),'{1}',t.date_a),'{2}',t.date_b)
            FROM
                t
            WHERE
                date_b IS NOT NULL
        ) di
    GROUP BY
        period;
```

EDIT:

The solution of Boneist is however better.

Comment: I wouldn't call this particularly simple; you're doing twice the amount of work you need to. Also what's with the distincts in the subqueries on the u table? Isn't errcode the primary key for that table?

Comment: `ERRCODE` isn't a primary key indeed, so the need of th distinct. I will correct that! Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure that the work is done twice, as each subquery is processing a different column. Can you please tell me what you mean ?

Comment: By "I'll correct that!" did you mean that you'd add a primary key on errcode in the u table? As for doing the work twice, I mean you're querying both tables twice, once in each of the union-all'd queries. You can achieve your aim by querying each table once, hence why I said you were doing twice as much work as you needed to.

Comment: did you mean that you'd add a primary key on errcode in the u table: yes. It should be a primary key any way, and I guess it will remove the need of distinct then.